# How can I show windows shared folders in QFileSystemModel

Tags: qt, qt4, qfilesystemmodel

I can show local files in QFileSystemModel

```
dirModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
dirModel->setRootPath((QDir::currentPath()));
ui->treeView->setModel(dirModel);
ui->treeView->hideColumn(1);
ui->treeView->hideColumn(2);
ui->treeView->hideColumn(3);
dirModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs);
ui->treeView->setRootIndex((dirModel)->index("C:"));
```

But I need to show shared folders. When I changed

```
ui->treeView->setRootIndex((dirModel)->index("C:"));
```

to

```
ui->treeView->setRootIndex((dirModel)->index("////MY-PC//shared"));
```

treeView become empty. How can I do this ?

I used Qt 4.8.6

Comment: Does `//MY-PC/shared` work? '/' is not an escape char so doubling it does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
QFileSystemModel* dirModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
dirModel->setRootPath("//localhost");
ui->treeView->setModel(dirModel);
ui->treeView->setRootIndex(dirModel->index("//localhost"));
```

This works like a charm for me.